# Ajax call to php function doesn't work PHP code

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, actions, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="BookingForm">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="emailId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitname" value="Send" />
</form>
<div id="container"></div>
```

My custom js file is in the following path: assets/js/makebooking.js
My JS file
**makebooking.js** :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {
 jQuery('#BookingForm').submit(validateForms);
 function validateForms(event) {
 event.preventDefault();

     var x =  MBAjax.ajaxurl;
     alert(x);

    jQuery.ajax({
      action:  'makeBooking',
      type:    "POST",
      url:     MBAjax.admin_url,
      success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
         //jQuery("#container" ).append(data);
      },
    fail: function(error){
        alert("error" + error);
    }
    });
     return false;
  }
});
```

**Functions.php** file:

```
// embed the javascript file that makes the AJAX request
wp_enqueue_script( 'make-booking-ajax','/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/js/makebooking.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
// declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
wp_localize_script( 'make-booking-ajax', 'MBAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

function makeBooking(){
    echo "Home again";
    return "Home";
}


add_action('wp_ajax_make_booking', 'makeBooking');
```

> **The problem is that the ajax call returns all the dom and not what the php function returns. The code in the php function does not work;
>   the echo message is not printed**

*The image below shows the issue*:

[image]

Thanks,

Federico

---

[image]

This is my status code and my response of ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `MBAjax.ajaxurl` and `MBAjax.admin_url` are probably not set. If it can't post to the correct Wordpress handler, then you will probably get a 404 page HTML returned instead of the PHP function return value.

You can test by hard-coding the ajax url to `url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",` and see if that fixes things.

Secondly, I have always added a hidden field on my forms with the action `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="make_booking">`

Try that and see how you get on. Also check your browser console `network` tab to see the AJAX request being sent. You can check the data you are POSTing and also the response you get back. Easier than trying to use alerts.

[image]

You can also use `console.log(x)` instead.

Update: I think you're missing sending anything in your AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   action : 'make_booking',
   type   : "POST",
   data   : {
      action: 'make_booking'
   }
   url    : MBAjax.admin_url,
   success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      //jQuery("#container" ).append(data);
   },
   fail: function(error){
      alert("error" + error);
   }
});
```

Try that.

Comment: It returns 400 status code (bad request)

Comment: Response is ' 0 '

Comment: OK, so where is it posting to - what's the URL (you can omit the actual domain name if need be)? What POST data is it sending? Can you screenshot the request screen?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
validateForms @ makebooking.js?ver=4.9.8:5
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Comment: Looking back at your code, it doesn't look like you're passing nay data in the AJAX request. Please see my update

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my code, but now it doesn't work. It shows the same code of the dom the return from ajax

Comment: What browser are you using - It would really help to see the actual POST data (again, see my answer for an update)

Comment: Chrome 69.0.3497.100

Comment: OK, that's good. You can open the developer tools `View > Developer > Developer Tools` and open the network tab - see my screenshot. We may have to move to chat soon..

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove note that you're including "action:" twice. The first instance (outside of the data object) isn't needed, and is not a valid .ajax() param, although I don't think it would cause any problems.

Comment: @Federico you should update your code with the current fixes so that people can figure out what's wrong. E.g. if you don't fix the action name it'll never work. If you're not logged in and haven't added the wp_ajax_nopriv_ action as suggested, it will never work too.

Answer (score 0):

The action seems to be incorrect on your Ajax call. As per the [wp_ajax_{action}](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) codex entry,

> The wp_ajax_ hooks follows the format "wp_ajax_$youraction", where $youraction is the 'action' field submitted to admin-ajax.php.

So try changing `action:  'makeBooking',` to `action:  'make_booking',` and see if it works then.

And if you want the ajax call to work for non-logged-in users, use also the [wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) action hook. Like this

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_make_booking', 'makeBooking');
```

**EDIT:** Oh, silly me. You're also missing `wp_die();` from the end of your ajax response. See [codex / AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for more details.

```
function makeBooking(){
    echo "Home again";
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

**EDIT 2:** You could also use [`wp_send_json`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) instead of echoing your response.

Comment: It does not work yet

Comment: Please see the edit regarding `wp_die()`

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: it returns the same code

Comment: On your code you're localizing `MBAjax.ajaxurl`, but use on the ajax call `MBAjax.admin_url`. Have you fixed that too? And Anastis pointed on the other answers comments you should update your code to show what has been changed.

Answer (score -1):

add below actions

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_makeBooking', 'makeBooking');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_makeBooking', 'makeBooking');
```

Comment: Sorry, Doesn't work